# What Impact will Multiple Minify and Optimizing Plugins have on a WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, minify, pagespeed-insights

I'm reviewing a WordPress website that has been running for four or five years. The website has a selection of WordPress plugins that they use to optimize the site's page speed, and I have a suspicion that they have just added multiple over time without thinking about the others. The plugins are the following:

- [Autoptimize](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/): A plugin that concatenates scripts and styles and has some inline and defer CSS features. Good customization settings. Currently active on the site.
- [Smush Image Compression](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/): Resizes and compresses most popular image formats for websites. Currently active.
- [Better WordPress Minify](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/): Combines and minifies CSS and JS scripts. Active on the site but only used to minify JS files.
- [PageSpeed Ninja](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/psn-pagespeed-ninja/): Another compression and minification plugin. Is active on the site.

So recently I ran the site through Page Speed Insights and far and away the most recommended suggestion to help the page load faster was server response times. In WordPress they recommend removing unused plugins and I want to reduce the optimization tools down to ideally 2 plugins. I was wondering if anyone here has any suggestions on possible pairings that might work (or have previously worked) well or whether it's just going to be easier to go through every plugin one by one, tinkering with the settings and running tests?
I am open to alternate plugins and strategies. Any wisdom would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard bag of tricks would be [W3 Total Cache](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) for optimising server response times via caching and minification of CSS and JS.

`Smush` is ok for image compression (although you will probably need premium for it to be completely useful) but a lot of the time you will find that a theme is not correctly configured to take full advantage of it (they don't offer different image sizes for different screen sizes).

I roll my own image optimiser that does everything locally but most people seem to say that [EWWW Image Optimizer](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/#description) gives the most flexibility for free. **not** a personal recommendation.

You only really need the W3 Total Cache plugin and an image optimiser, beyond that you are into actually learning how to optimise a site properly as all of the other plugins tend to make a mess.

Comment: +1 because I agree with this answer and use w3 total cache. Smush and EWWW work great! I found "Imsanity" doesn't put banners in the notice areas asking for reviews or premium subscriptions but still does a decent job of controlling the massive files my clients upload. My clients aren't too tech savvy most of the time so I try to keep everything silent and in the background. edit: I'm super interested in building in my own system but never find the time. Thats pretty cool!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it to be honest, it took ages! If you want to poke around https://netdec.com you will see some strange stuff for images. Basically I use the screen width and the width of the image to serve up a pixel perfect sized image and decide whether to send a jpg or a webp depending on browser features. I also have a 'point of interest' so that on mobile the image gets cropped as well as resized so the most relevant part of the image is focused. Hope that makes sense. Have a poke around the code and see if you can piece it together :-)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the advice. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Thank you for this. If anyone was interested the theme is The7 and there is a bit of info I found about its speed and compatibility with the WP Rocket plugin (https://wp-rocket.me/blog/testing-the7-wordpress-theme-how-fast-is-it/). I dunno if the website owner will go for all the recommendations but I think it'll be a good starting point and maybe make the owner a little more discerning about plugins.